# Table View doesn't insert the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My goal is really simple whenever someone is done clicking the last cell then simply add a new cell but seems like it doesn't work.

Here's the scenario the initial state of the view controller

[image]

Whenever someone clicks either **Current** or **Where to** row, it will spawn a google auto complete controller

[image]

Assume that **Current** row will get populated and the only row that user has to click is **Where To** and once the user has completed the **Where To**, I want to add another row.

Here's how it looks like

[image]

Here's the code

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    // Array for tableView
    var locationArray = ["", "Where to?"]

    // To be used when user clicks the row
    var currentLocationVal = false
    var whereToLocationVal = false

    @IBOutlet var locationTableView: UITableView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Table View stuff
        locationTableView.delegate = self
        locationTableView.dataSource = self 

    }

     // Google Autocomplete function to spawn the google autocomplete controller, the extension will be at the bottom of the code
     func googleAutoCompleteController() {
        let googleAutoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        googleAutoCompleteController.delegate = self as GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate
        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .establishment
        googleAutoCompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
        present(googleAutoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    // This is the function that will add the new row/cell
    func addedPromoTableCells() {
        locationArray.append("Promo")

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: locationArray.count - 1, section: 0)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.locationTableView.beginUpdates()
            self.locationTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.locationTableView.endUpdates()
     }
}
```

The `addedPromoTableCells()` function is the code that I want to run

**Extension on ViewController for tableView delegate** (Don't want to make the code too long)

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return locationArray.count
    }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GetLocation", for: indexPath)

     let location = locationArray[indexPath.row]


        if let locationCell = cell as? GetLocationTableViewCell {
            locationCell.locationTitle.text = location

        }

     return cell

     }

    // table view delegate function that will spawn the google autocomplete controller when user select one of the rows.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        switch indexPath.row {

        case 0:
            let selected = indexPath.row
            if (selected == 0) {
                currentLocationVal = true
                googleAutoCompleteController()
            }
        case 1:
            let selected = indexPath.row
            if (selected == 1) {
                whereToLocationVal = true
                googleAutoCompleteController()
            }
        default :
            print("Number out of range")
        }


    }

}
```

**Extension for GoogleAutocomplete code**

```
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

    // Handle the user's selection.
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

        // First cell
        let firstLocationCell = locationTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? GetLocationTableViewCell
        // Second Cell
        let secondLocationCell = locationTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)) as? GetLocationTableViewCell

        // if currentLocationVal is true then update the first cell 
        if (currentLocationVal == true) {
            firstLocationCell?.locationTitle.text = place.name
            currentLocationVal = false
         // if whereToVal is true then update the second cell 
        } else if (whereToLocationVal == true) {
            secondLocationCell?.locationTitle.text = place.name
            addedPromoTableCells() // This is where the line supposed to be executed
            whereToLocationVal = false
        }



        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

 // There are more codes here, but don'w want to complicate things because it is not relevant to the use case.
}
```

So whenever the second row has completed the table view doesn't get updated.

Comment: Have you tried with only `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: I tried it and it reloads everything, meaning it resets everything. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Is your `Current` `Where To` this two elements are in an `UITableView`?

Comment: I created based on the array. which is `var locationArray = ["", "Where to?"]`

Comment: You can take a look at the code